# Validation in SharePoint List (IF, AND, OR)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column-formula, validation

I need:

> If [estado]= "concluido" > turn into mandatory columns [Diagnostico Final] and [Atribuído a]

And:

> If [estado]= "Executando Trabalho" or "em transito" or "em Pausa" > turn mandatory only the column [Atribuido a]

And:

> If [estado] = "Aguardando Atribuição" or "Cancelada" then do nothing.

Here's the formula I'm trying to apply:

```
=IF(AND([Estado]<>"Aguardando Atribuição";[Estado]<>"Cancelada");IF([Estado]="Concluído";IF(AND([Atribuído a]<>"";[Diagnóstico Final]<>"")TRUE;FALSE);IF([Atribuído a]<>"";TRUE;FALSE));TRUE)
```

Comment: Are you getting any error while using this formula or is it not working as expected?

Comment: Hi, did you try formula given in my answer below? Is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula in **List Validation** settings:

```
=IF([estado]="Concluido";IF(OR(ISBLANK([Diagnostico Final]);ISBLANK([Atribuido a])); FALSE;TRUE);IF(OR([estado]="Executando Trabalho";[estado]="em transito";[estado]="em Pausa");NOT(ISBLANK([Atribuido a));TRUE))
```